# MySQL Doesn't Run in SqLite Can I Build it with Doctrine2 Query Builder?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, doctrine-orm

I have a nice query that is updating a "parent" (Observation) value depending on what is set from the "child" (Action) table. An Observation can have many Actions, and when they are all marked 'resolved' then the parent Observation is marked resolved too.

This is the MySQL script.

```
UPDATE observation
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            co.id AS obs_id,
            SUM(at.resolved) AS tasks_resolved,
            COUNT(at.id) as total_tasks 
        FROM observation co 
        INNER JOIN action_task at ON at.observation_id = co.id
        WHERE co.id = (
            SELECT task.observation_id FROM action_task task
            WHERE task.id = 5
        )
    ) val ON val.obs_id = observation.id
    SET observation.resolved = CASE
        WHEN val.tasks_resolved=val.total_tasks THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
;
```

I wanted to bring this query into a Doctrine 2 Repository. I tried for an afternoon to build a Query Builder script for it, but ended up running the whole script from the `EXEC` command.

I started building the functional tests, but it threw an error because I cannot have an **INNER JOIN** in an `UPDATE` - This is because the **INNER JOIN** is only allowed in MySQL.

So I updated the Query to remove the **INNER JOIN** on the `UPDATE`. It looks like this:

```
UPDATE observation, (
        SELECT
            SUM(at.resolved) AS tasks_resolved,
            COUNT(at.id) as total_tasks 
        FROM observation co 
        INNER JOIN action_task at ON at.observation_id = co.id
        WHERE co.id = (
            SELECT task.observation_id FROM action_task task
            WHERE task.id = 5
        )
    ) val
    SET observation.resolved = CASE
        WHEN val.tasks_resolved=val.total_tasks THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
    WHERE observation.id = (
        SELECT task.observation_id FROM action_task task
        WHERE task.id = 5
    )
;
```

I am now facing a problem where the SQL runs fine when it is used within the site, but it fails when I am trying to run the functional tests. It is throwing the error:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ",": syntax error`

The normal site is running on MySQL and the Functional Tests are run using SqLite. I think it would save more stuffing around to build the query with Query Builder and save the cross-database issues.

I am wondering if there is a way to write the query with Query Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comma still is a [join operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause) (or it would be if it were allowed in an UPDATE).

The UPDATE statement itself allows only a single table.
You have to do the lookups with correlated subqueries:

```
UPDATE observation
SET resolved = (SELECT SUM(resolved) = COUNT(id)
                FROM action_task
                WHERE observation_id = observation.id)
WHERE id = (SELECT observation_id
            FROM action_task
            WHERE id = 5)
```